# Subcategory permalinks in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have my store with parent category and child category.
I can open child category in 2 ways:

```
store.com/parentcategoryname/childcategoryname
```

and

```
store.com/childcategorynamey
```

and i want use only second way.
But problem is my category menu shows only first permalink everywhere:

```
store.com/parentcategoryname/childcategoryname
```

How can i change this?
i want use only links like this:

```
store.com/childcategorynamey
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using code I believe this answers your question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291018/permalinks-for-woocommerce-categories-and-subcategories

Hope this helps. Please inform me if you face any problems.

Comment: parent category still is in url :(

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you, the second way is not appropriate for your problem. I suggest the first one and will edit my answer by removing second option.